# Sinatra can't find do_sqlite3

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

I'm running Sinatra and i have datamapper installed, but when i require it and try to use it, I get an error saying this:

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could no
t find 'do_sqlite3' (~> 0.10.6) among 46 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
```

It traces back to this line:

```
require 'data_mapper'
DataMapper::setup(:default, "sqlite3://db/development.db") #this line
```

I even included the gem for it in my gemfile. What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you have the `dm-sqlite-adapter` gem installed?

Comment: Yes, I have that in the gem file too.

Comment: What's that wild `<br>` in the code?

Comment: Sorry about that, it was just a formatting mistake.

Comment: Did you try `sqlite3:///db/development.db` (note 3 slashes)

Comment: It's not Sinatra that can't find it, it's Ruby.

Comment: What command are you using to run your app? Are you using `bundle exec`?

Comment: @kunalbhat i tried that and it didn't work.
@matt i just use `rackup` but i tried running that command and i still get the error.

Comment: Here is the code for the whole project: https://github.com/calebdre/Sinatra-Starter

Comment: `bundle exec rackup` is the command you need (not just `bundle exec` by itself). You’ll probably need to `bundle install` first to install the missing gems.